# Functional O(1) append and O(n) iteration from first element list data structure

Tags: data-structures, f#, functional-programming

I'm looking for a functional data structure that supports the following operations:

- Append, O(1)
- In order iteration, O(n)

A normal functional linked list only supports O(n) append, while I could use a normal LL and then reverse it, the reverse operation would be O(n) also which (partially) negates the O(1) cons operation.

Comment: have you looked at System.Collections.Generic.LinkedList<T>?

Comment: Yes, but it's not immutable, which is a requirement.

Comment: How about functional queues? http://www.randomhacks.net/articles/2007/02/08/haskell-queues-without-pointers.  This may not cut it at first, but it could be a start.   Keeping a stack, and then reversing a copy to iterate in order would be an extra O(n) operation, but that would still make iteration O(n).

Answer (score 9):

You can use John Hughes's constant-time append lists, which seem nowadays to be called `DList`.  The representation is a function from lists to lists: the empty list is the identity function; append is composition, and singleton is cons (partially applied).  In this representation every enumeration will cost you `n` allocations, so that may not be so good.

The alternative is to make the same algebra as a data structure:

```
type 'a seq = Empty | Single of 'a | Append of 'a seq * 'a seq
```

Enumeration is a tree walk, which will either cost some stack space or will require some kind of zipper representation.  Here's a tree walk that converts to list but uses stack space:

```
let to_list t =
  let rec walk t xs = match t with
  | Empty -> xs
  | Single x -> x :: xs
  | Append (t1, t2) -> walk t1 (walk t2 xs) in
  walk t []
```

Here's the same, but using constant stack space:

```
let to_list' t =
  let rec walk lefts t xs = match t with
  | Empty -> finish lefts xs
  | Single x -> finish lefts (x :: xs)
  | Append (t1, t2) -> walk (t1 :: lefts) t2 xs
  and finish lefts xs = match lefts with
  | [] -> xs
  | t::ts -> walk ts t xs in
  walk [] t []
```

You can write a fold function that visits the same elements but doesn't actually reify the list; just replace cons and nil with something more general:

```
val fold : ('a * 'b -> 'b) -> 'b -> 'a seq -> 'b

let fold f z t =
  let rec walk lefts t xs = match t with
  | Empty -> finish lefts xs
  | Single x -> finish lefts (f (x, xs))
  | Append (t1, t2) -> walk (t1 :: lefts) t2 xs
  and finish lefts xs = match lefts with
  | [] -> xs
  | t::ts -> walk ts t xs in
  walk [] t z
```

That's your linear-time, constant-stack enumeration.  Have fun!

Comment: Note that `seq` is already used as the F# name for `IEnumerable` and that it is tempting to use `Seq.append` but that would stack overflow.

Comment: He's asking for "In order iteration, O(n)". This solution is O(2n), which in the end it's the same cost as reversing the list and then iterating.

Answer (score 5):

I believe you can just use standard functional linked list:

- To append element, you can use *cons* (which is *O(1)*)
- To iterate elements in the order in which they were inserted, you can first reverse the list,
  (which is *O(N)*) and then traverse it, which is also *O(N)* (and *2xO(N)* is still just *O(N)*).

Comment: Append is an operation on *lists*, not an element and a list.  The cost of append is the length of the left argument.

Answer (score 5):

How about a difference list?

```
type 'a DList = DList of ('a list -> 'a list)

module DList =
  let append (DList f) (DList g) = (DList (f << g))
  let cons x (DList f) = (DList (fun l -> x::(f l)))
  let snoc (DList f) x = (DList (fun l -> f(x::l)))
  let empty = DList id
  let ofList = List.fold snoc empty
  let toList (DList f) = f []
```

Comment: I hate it when people use this data structure without giving credit to [John Hughes](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=8475).

Answer (score 2):

You could create a functional Deque, which provides `O(1)` adding to either end, and `O(N)` for iteration in either direction. Eric Lippert wrote about an interesting version of an immutable Deque [on his blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/02/12/immutability-in-c-part-eleven-a-working-double-ended-queue.aspx) note that if you look around you will find the other parts of the series, but that is the explanation of the final product. Note also that with a bit of tweaking it can be modified to utilize F# discriminated unions and pattern matching (although that is up to you).

Another interesting property of this version, `O(1)` peek, removal, and add, from either end (i.e. dequeueLeft, dequeueRight, dequeueLeft, dequeueRight, etc. is still O(N), versus O(N*N) with a double list method).

Answer (score 1):

What about a [circularly-linked list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#Circularly_linked_list)? It supports O(*1*) appends and O(*n*) iteration.